# When to allocate memory for an array in C++?

Tags: c++

Suppose I would like to create an array and would like to build the data and add it to the array in a function. The array is to be used outside the function, I just want to organize the creation into a function. Is it best to allocate the memory for the array outside of the function, and then pass a pointer to that location to the function? Or would it be better to allocate the memory for the array inside the function using new and then return a pointer to the location in memory? Or is there another thing I should do?

I guess the benefits to the first is that I can choose whether to allocate the memory on the stack or on the heap depending on how/why I am calling this function. Like maybe this array doesn't need to be on the heap, I just need it for one function that calls it. I don't necessarily have to worry about the memory creation and deletion in the function, since the outside code would handle that. The benefits to the second is I suppose it's simpler.

Comment: `std::vector`...

Comment: Just use a `std::vector`, pass it around by reference (`const` if necessary) and then you don't have to worry about memory allocation.

Comment: Or even better, use `std::vector<>` :).

Comment: "I just want to organize the creation into a function" .. this is about c++ not c, right? Creating stuff and allocating memory is done in constructors, more over you dont have to do this, as there are ready to use containers, e.g. `std::vector`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use a `std::vector`. This kind of thing is exactly what it's there for.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you want to do. Stack is much faster to allocate of course, but whether this matters depends on the context.

If you want to encapsulate what happens to this array, the third option is to enclose it in an object and run the initialization in the constructor. This way rather than hiding the allocation in the initialization, you'd be hiding the initialization in the allocation: every time you create an array of this type, it is invariably initialized in that way.

Example with dynamic memory:

```
class MyArray {
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> array;
  public:
    MyArray(int n) : array(new int[n]) {
        /* initialization here */
    }
    int& operator [](int i) { return array[i]; }
}
```

Of course then you have to pass it around as its own class `MyArray` rather than a pointer (but you should *not* pass pointers around anyway), and you have to implement methods to access the array from outside the object, like `operator []`.

Even if you encapsulate it, please use smart pointers: while `vector` still has some overhead, `unique_ptr` is just as light and fast as a regular pointer, but ensures that the dynamic memory will be freed as soon as `MyArray` goes out of scope, without need to place a `delete` on every possible path.

Or if you know at compile time how long they need to be you can put them on the stack of course

```
 template<int len>
 class MyArray {
    int array[len];
  public:
    MyArray(int n) {
        /* initialization here */
    }
    int& operator [](int i) { return array[i]; }
}
```